# Json parsing right solution

Tags: android

I am stuck in a problem. I am getting the Json response like

```
{
"Result":[
   "Entertainment",
   "Business",
   "Sports",
   "Technology"]
}
```

I am able to get the first value i,e Result value like this
 in the post-execute loop response is

```
["Entertainment","Business","Sports","Technology"]
```

Now the problem is that I am getting the response as string not as array. So how could I fetch these values separately.

Answer (score 2):

> problem is that I am getting the response as string not as array

=> As you said you are having response as a String, then you just need to create JSONObject with the response string you are getting and then fetch JSONArray from it using below:

```
try{
    JSONObject objJSON = new JSONObject(objResponse);
    JSONArray arrayResponse = objJSON.getJSONArray("Result");

    // iterate through the JSONArray and fetch one by one string
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: @Vyas Learn JSON Parsing [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/).

Answer (score 0):

Like this (and `jsonString` is your source json response from server):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject( jsonString );
JSONArray resultArray = json.getJSONArray("Result");
```

and then simply iterate over `resultArray` and `get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch each `String` value of the `Results` array, from your `JSON` string like this:-

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray resultArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result");
for(int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++){
    System.out.println(resultArray.getString(i)); // Get each String.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your json like this

```
try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject("");
        JSONArray arr=obj.getJSONArray("Result");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray resultArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result");

for(int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++){  

  JSONObject jsonObj =   resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
  String Entertainment= jObject.getString("Entertainment");
  String    Business= jObject.getString("Business");
  String    Sports = jObject.getString("Sports");
  String Technology = jObject.getString("Technology ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to parse your `JSONArray` and return an `ArrayList` of Strings , try this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result");
    if(jsonArray!= null) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            arrayResult.add(arrayResult.getString(i));
        }
    }
```

**NB : you should put this in** `try catch` **bloc to catch** `JSONException`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
   // getting JSON string from URL
   JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONObjectFromUrl(url);
   Log.e("json is", "--------------"+json);
   programResponse   =   json.getString("Result");
   Log.e("in the post-execute loop", "in the post-execute loop response is"+programResponse);
   JSONArray arrayResponse = new JSONArray(programResponse);
   for(int i = 0; i < arrayResponse.length(); i++){
   //JSONArray innerJsonArray = json.getJSONArray(i);
   String jsonObject = arrayResponse.getString(i);
   System.out.println(jsonObject);
   Log.e("length is", "--------------"+jsonObject);
   programValues.add(jsonObject);
}
```